Why doesn't boost::regex recognize escaped "less-than" sign?
In the following 4 assertions only the last one fails:
int main() {
    assert(boost::regex_match("\"", boost::regex("\\\"")));
    assert(boost::regex_match(".", boost::regex("\\.")));
    assert(!boost::regex_match("a", boost::regex("\\.")));
    assert(boost::regex_match("<", boost::regex("\\<")));  // this one fails
}

Why then the first two are passed?

The default is Perl Regular Expression Syntax and < is not a special character in all positions (the other characters in the code above are).

You had a problem.  You thought "I know, I can fix it with a regex!".  Congratulations, you now have two problems: the original one, and a regex.

Thanks! In the link you provided the sign < is used in pattern matching. Why then not to escape it? And the other note is that assert(boost::regex_match("\"", boost::regex("\""))) is passed just fine. What's the point to escape it then?

Any other escape Any other escape sequence matches the character that is escaped, for example \@ matches a literal '@'.  So "\\\"" matches ".

@MaximPopov I think the boost documentation is wrong. < doesn't match a word boundary.  \< seems to do accoding to some. Never used that myself though. Anyway, you should be using just "<"
